# How To Install Generic Android OS In Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: android

Where and how to install a generic Android 2.2 OS in Samsung Galaxy S?

Comment: Such questions are offtopic here. You need to ask either on Samsung forums or on http://superuser.com

Comment: Probably a better fit on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You need to root the phone, get an Android installation ROM and install. Go to http://forum.xda-developers.com/ and search there. You WILL find a ROM and "how-to" there. It's the main site for getting this type of stuff. They should also tell you how to root the phone, so that you can install the software.

T